# Scala slick - How to take a column value from different tables

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have 2 tables: Main and Update with columns name, id and department. 
I would like to read the Main table first, and if the department field value is empty, i could  like to read it from Update table.

For example, from the below table, I should get the department value for KING from Update table.

How to achieve this using scala slick with out running plain sql queries?

**Main**

```
+-------+----+------------+
+ name  | id | department +            
+-------+----+------------+
| KING  | 10 |            |
| BLAKE | 30 | SALES      |
+-------+----+------------+
```

**Update**

```
+-------+----+------------+
+ name  | id | department +  
+-------+----+------------+
| KING  | 10 | SYSTEMS    |
| BLAKE | 30 | SALES      |
+-------+----+------------+
```

Here is the plain sql query

```
SELECT 
m.`name`,
m.`id`,
if(m.`department`='', u.`department`) as `department`
FROM `Main` m
FROM `Update` u ON m.id=u.id
```

I have following code defined so far ...

```
case class Main(name: Option[String],
                id: Option[int],
                department: Option[String])

case class Update(name: Option[String],
                  id: Option[int],
                  department: Option[String])

lazy val mainQuery = TableQuery[MainTableDefinition]
lazy val updateQuery = TableQuery[UpdateTableDefinition]

class MainTableDefinition(tag: Tag) extends Table[Main](tag, "Main") {
      def name = column[Option[String]]("name")
      def id = column[Option[int]]("id")
      def department = column[Option[String]]("department")

      override def * =
         (name, id, department)<> (Main.tupled, Main.unapply)
}

class UpdateTableDefinition(tag: Tag) extends Table[Update](tag, "Update") {
      def name = column[Option[String]]("name")
      def id = column[Option[int]]("id")
      def department = column[Option[String]]("department")

      override def * =
         (name, id, department)<> (Update.tupled, Update.unapply)
}

val query = for {
  m <- mainQuery 
  u <- updateQuery if m.id === u.id
} yield (m, u)

db.run(query.to[List].result)
```

Comment: You might want to define a custom function `coalesce` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html) and use it ```val query = for {
  m <- mainQuery 
  u <- updateQuery if m.id === u.id
  department = coalesce(m.department, u.department)
} yield (m.id, department)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your example:

```
SELECT 
m.`name`,
m.`id`,
if(m.`department`='', u.`department`) as `department`
FROM `Main` m
FROM `Update` u ON m.id=u.id
```

seems to fetch a combination of values from two tables.

**DB level solution**

On DB level maybe something like this would work for you:

```
val query = for {
  m <- mainQuery 
  u <- updateQuery if m.id === u.id
} yield {
  (m.id, m.name, m.department.ifNull(u.department))
}
```

which I believe is very close your original, desired query (though to be honest I am not entirely sure how `ifNull` is translated on all databases).

**Application level solution**

On application level, assuming that you have single case class:

```
case class NameDepartment(name: Option[String],
                  id: Option[int],
                  department: Option[String])
```

(which btw you can you for *unpacked* type for both table definitions as they are identical) it might look like this:

```
  val fetchOperation = (for {
    m <- mainQuery 
    u <- updateQuery if m.id === u.id
  } yield (m, u)
  ).result.map { results => 
    results.map { case (m, u) =>
       NameDepartment(m.name, m.id, m.department.orElse(u.department))
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Cannot confidently say that this worked.

Using maps multiple times was confusing.

Comment: I assume you tried second version only?

Did you check the first option? The one indicated by: "On DB level maybe something like this would work for you" <- it has no multiple maps.

Also what do say "Cannot ... say this worked"? You were confused by multiple maps (in second example) but it does what you need or it doesn't work (compile or return results you wanted to achieve)? Just curious.

EDIT: Added sections to my answer to indicate clearly that there are two solutions there.

Comment: Actually I had to redesign the architecture and I have another question which is similar to this.

However I have tried this with my data and your solution works. Thanks for the help. 

Accepted your answer.